# How I can switch to element in doctype html ? I use switch to iframe and is not work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, doctype, katalon-studio

I have problem with localization element (❌ Unable to click on object). I use switch To iframe for example

```
WebUI.switchToFrame(findTestObject('Rejestracja Podmiotu/iFrame'), 20)
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Rejestracja Podmiotu/input_OBSZARY DZIAANIA_s_obszar_dzialalnosci-sectionxf-1532grid-12-gridc_obszar_dzialalnosci-controlxf-16481'))
```

Iframe looks like this

[image]

And my element is in !doctype html. And it is input.

[image]

And my question is how can I use this input in my test ? Somebody can tell me ?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: ❌ Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Podmiot ver.1.0/Page_PUESC - seap-testskgpl/input_OBSZARY DZIAANIA_s_obszar_dzialalnosci-sectionxf-1532grid-12-gridc_obszar_dzialalnosci-controlxf-16481' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Podmiot ver.1.0/Page_PUESC - seap-testskgpl/input_OBSZARY DZIAANIA_s_obszar_dzialalnosci-sectionxf-1532grid-12-gridc_obszar_dzialalnosci-controlxf-16481'

Comment: Please, check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching to an iframe element, it is usually a good idea to wait for the element to be clickable before clicking (because basically iframe is loading another page inside of the frame). So, try:

```
WebUI.switchToFrame(findTestObject('Rejestracja Podmiotu/iFrame'), 20)
WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Rejestracja Podmiotu/input_OBSZARY DZIAANIA_s_obszar_dzialalnosci-sectionxf-1532grid-12-gridc_obszar_dzialalnosci-controlxf-16481'), 10)
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Rejestracja Podmiotu/input_OBSZARY DZIAANIA_s_obszar_dzialalnosci-sectionxf-1532grid-12-gridc_obszar_dzialalnosci-controlxf-16481'))
```